# Change sqrt bracket size

Tags: brackets, sqrt

This code

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &  \sqrt{Var_\nu(f)} \\
        &  \sqrt{Var_\mu(f)}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

produces

[image]

As you can see, the sizes of the brackets of the square root are different. I don't know why, but this depends of the letter in the subscript.

Does anyone know how to change sqrt so that both have the same size? (preferably the size of the first square root)

> Comment: I think this happens inside the split environment. I don't mind changing this, but I still would like the formulas aligned.

Comment: \mu is deeper than \nu so the sqrt extends to cover it. (unrelated but define a \Var that uses roman not math italic so it doesn't look like V ar

Comment: Try `\sqrt{\smash{Var_\mu(f)}}` (and yes, as David Carlisle says, replace Var by a command).

Comment: ...or maybe `\sqrt{Var_{\smash{\mu}}(f)}`

Comment: @ParthaD. no. \smash works in math mode you should not use `\text` here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Did not know that... I just edited it (to a little-bit improvement of @Gaussler).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about adding a `\strut` for the first `\sqrt`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    &  \sqrt{\strut Var_\nu(f)} \\
    &  \sqrt{Var_\mu(f)}
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ___Thank you :D

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Var{Var}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &  \sqrt{\smash[b]{\Var_\nu(f)}} \\
        &  \sqrt{\smash[b]{\Var_\mu(f)}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

where the `\smash[b]` hides the depth of the expression.

Comment: I would consider doing `\DeclareMathOperator\Var{V\!ar}`, as I don’t like the space between the `V` and the `a`. Also, for the sake of promoting good style, maybe you should replace `_\mu` and `_\nu` by `_{\mu}` and `_{\nu}`.

Comment: Well, it could be that your single token expanded to `x^2`. I think it’s better to promote good, consistent style that works everywhere.

Comment: Agreed. If I were in charge of LaTeX, `_` and `^` would have been made active characters a long time ago. So, probably, would `$`. Other than slightly changed behaviour, such as what we just discussed, there really are no issues with this, right?

Comment: Or, as you know from my `semantex` stuff, if I were in charge of LaTeX, it would be much more like `\Var[measure=\measuremu,map=\vf]`. `;-)`

Comment: Well, one could use a solution like in HTML, where users can actively choose `strict` HTML by writing a line at the top of their documents. The HTML community did not get a mental breakdown over the introduction of this option.

Comment: And then we look forward to `\documenttype` (which activates LaTeX v. 3.0), `\documentparadigm` (which activates LaTeX v. 4.0), `\documentcategory` which activates LaTeX v. 5.0), and `\documentweranoutofsynonymsforclass` (which activates LaTeX v. 6.0). `;-)`

Comment: ___Thank you :D